# Changing the font size in autoplot and tracks functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor, ggbiplot

I am using the tracks function from ggbio package, but I am unable to change the size in the x axis.

The df dataframe:

```
chr    start     end           id
chr12 72065147 72204484 ENSBTAG00000045751
chr12 72529373 72690449 ENSBTAG00000047181
chr12 73574461 73704802 ENSBTAG00000046041
chr12 73890111 73977633 ENSBTAG00000047764
chr12 74198711 74199129 ENSBTAG00000047360
chr12 74816044 74978179 ENSBTAG00000023309
chr12 75457896 75536848 ENSBTAG00000026070
chr12 75664651 75870596 ENSBTAG00000039714
chr12 76758753 76864805 ENSBTAG00000003568
chr12 76867833 76922959 ENSBTAG00000003569
chr12 76958977 77024110 ENSBTAG00000012065
chr12 77032585 77176916 ENSBTAG00000004401
```

Code:

```
library(ggbio)
library(GenomicRanges)
gr <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df, TRUE)
ex <- autoplot(gr, ylab = "Soft") + theme(text = element_text(size=20))
tracks(ex)
```

In this example just the y axis in changed by theme `(size =20)`. The x axis continues very small. Interestingly if I don´t use tracks function the two axis (x and y) change normally to my desired size `(size =20)`.

However, I have several objects to plot in track from my actual data, which  coerce me to use tracks function. Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: Why use `tracks` if you are plotting only one track - `df`?

Comment: Actually this was a bad example. I tried to simplify. I had fixed it now. Thank you

Comment: cross posted at https://www.biostars.org/p/111949/